# .Xauthority, .asoundrc, .bashrc appear out of nowhere in Git repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, git, bugs

The files

- `.Xauthority`
- `.asoundrc`
- `.bashrc`

appear out of nowhere (I don't know when) in Git repositories. The files are not managed by Git. One of the repositories is cloned from GitHub, the other was created on local PC and pushed to GitHub.

What is the cause of this?

Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. I run:

```
firejail --noprofile --disable-mnt --nogroups --nonewprivs --notv --nou2f --novideo --private=. --seccomp "$@"
```

Hm, but why this command creates such iles?

Comment: Weird, the file appears even if I add `--shell=none`. What is this?